# How to install **.apk to android emulator?

Tags: android, gradle, android-emulator, adb

I am using gradle installDebug command to install apk on a emulator. I can see the output from the command saying: "Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Nexus_5_API_22(AVD) - 5.1'". But I couldn't find the app on my emulator. Then I tried to use adb install command to install the apk. It showed as below:

**2229 KB/s (1093808 bytes in 0.479s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk
Success**

The command run successfully but I still couldn't find it on my emulator. Does anyone know how to find the install apk on the emulator?

Comment: Why don't you install and **run the app** from gradle also? In any case, your application's main activity could be missing the launcher category's intent filter. Could you show us your manifest.

Comment: After modify mainfest file, it works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Now with Android Studio 2.2 you just have to drag your app to the emulator. After some seconds the app will be installed

[image]

[image]